# How to call Account settings in android programatically

Tags: android, android-activity

Here is my code.

```
Intent i=new Intent();
try {
    i.setClassName(this, (Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT));
    startActivity(i);
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I am getting Null pointer exception. Please help

Comment: from where are you calling this code? please also share the logcat logs..

Comment: Am calling this from the activity class

Comment: Try in device ,  then say error

Comment: startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT));

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent intent=new  Intent(Settings.ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS);
startActivity(intent);
```

For add gmail

You can use [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html).

```
AccountManager acm = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
             acm.addAccount("com.google", null, null, null, thisclassname.this, 
             null, null);
```

Comment: I want to to launch adding Gmail account. Is that not possible?

Comment: I just want to launch the Add account in android. Not adding account

Comment: Which screen do you want to open , "settings" or "Accounts & Sync Setting " or  "add an account " ??

Comment: Does the addAccount call above return an intent? If it does you can fire that to start the activity. Likewise just pass an activity into the addAccount call and the gmail addAccount activity should start. This is assuming the gmail account type is correct